# Как найти getChildFragmentManager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Макет активности состоит из одного фрагмента. Макет фрагмента состоит из TextView и FrameLayout (в который буду вставлять дочерний фрагмент). В учебнике написано, что для того, чтобы вставить дочерний фрагмент мне нужно получить доступ к менеджеру дочерних фрагментов. С помощью getChildFragmentManager(). У меня нормально работает getFragmentManager(). Но если я пытаюсь вызвать getChildFragmentManager(), то оказывается, что такого метода нет. Подскажите, в чём моя ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: А где вы вызываете getChildFragmentManager? Это надо делать во фрагменте

Comment: Да, действительно. Теперь всё работает